# FileOutputStream vs ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, file, stream

I'm reading somebody else's code. Here's the gist of it.

A class compresses and decompresses files using GZIPInputStream and GZIPOutputStream.

Here's a snippet of what goes on during compression. `inputFile` and `outputFile` are instances of the class `File`.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

//the following function copies an input stream to an output stream
IOUtils.copy(fis,gzos);

//outputFile is the compressed file
...
```

Now, here's what's going on during decompression.

```
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//copies input stream to output stream
IOUtils.copy(gzis,baos);

//this method does as its name suggests
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(outputFile, baos.toByteArray());

//outputFile is the decompressed file
...
```

What's a possible reason the original programmer chose `FileOutputStream` during compression and `ByteArrayOutputStream` during decompression? It confuses me.

Unless there's a good reason, I think I'm changing them to be consistant to avoid future confusion. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Are IOUtils and FileUtils propritary or from a lib like commons-io?

Comment: @sblundy, they are from libs like commons-io.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heh, sounds like they copied and pasted code from different sources? :-P No, seriously, unless you need to inspect the decompressed data, you can just use a `BufferedOutputStream` for both compression and decompression.

Comment: In that case, would you recommend my using `new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)` instead of `new FileOutputStream(outputFile)`? Would there be a performance gain?

Comment: I would, it is likely this appeared to improve performance when the real solution was to use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: Yep. BufferedInput and BufferedOuput is the efficient way to go.

Comment: @Russell: Indeed, yes, use buffered streams for both places. (Not that I needed to say this, because two others already did, but just to bring some closure to your question. :-))

Comment: P.S. Consider wrapping the input streams in `BufferedInputStream` too, again both for compression and decompression.

Answer (score 7):

The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is more memory hogging since it stores the entire content in Java's memory (in flavor of a `byte[]`). The `FileOutputStream` writes to disk directly and is hence less memory hogging. I don't see any sensible reason to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` in this particular case. It is not modifying the individual bytes afterwards. It just get written unchanged to file afterwards. It's thus an unnecessary intermediate step.

Answer (score 4):

The programmer used FileInputStream during compression and used buffer when decompressing. I think that the reason was that if you are failing duinr reading the file nothing bad happens. You just fail and a exception is thrown.

If you are failing while decompressing and you already started writing to file the file is corrupted. So he decided to write buffer first and then when decompression is completed to writer the buffer on disk. This solution is OK if you are dealing with relatively small files. Otherwise this requires to much memory and could produce OutOfMemeoryError.

I'd extract zip directly to *temporary* file and then rename the temporary file to its permanent name. Finally block should care to delete the temporary file.

Comment: Good thinking. There seemed to be no where in the code to take care of failed writes, so I guess in this particular case, it's copy paste or written at different times.

Comment: very easy to understand your answer. thank you Alex

Answer (score 3):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` would give him/her a nice `OutOfMemoryError`?

Seriously, they were probably done at different times. If you can, I'd consult the VCS logs.